# Updating a variable in a function

Tags: python

Im new to python and im sure the solution to this is simple but I can't quite get my head around it. Im trying to write a function that updates a variable when the function is called. The first time the function is called the variable should be 0 everytime the function is called after that the variable should be 1.

if i was to call the function 5 times i would expect this outcome.

```
status = 0
status = 1
status = 1
status = 1
status = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def function(status):
    if function.wasCalled == True:
        status = 1
    function.wasCalled = True
    return status

function.wasCalled = False  
status = 0

print(function(status))
print(function(status))
print(function(status))
print(function(status))
print(function(status))
print(function(status))
```

Comment: I believe that this works for what i wanted to do. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a global variable and update it inside the function.

```
status = 0

def my_function():
    global status    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    status = 1

my_function()
print status # Should be 1
```

This would do the trick. Or you want to increment status each time the function is called? Like, call it 5 times and status = 5 ??
Try this here: https://ideone.com/KnQEWx

Comment: I just want to increment the value of status once. So the first time my_function is called status would equal 0 then everytime after that status would equal 1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

def YourName():
 x=1
 while True:
  if x==1:
   print(0)
  elif x!=1:
   print(1)
YourName()